# Issue when converting a string to an integer

Tags: ruby

Please excuse as this is my first question here on S/O. I am trying to create a .rb file that will ask a few questions from the user including their whole name and favourite number. I am retrieving the favourite number and adding 1 to it and displaying it back to the user.

Here is my code

```
puts "Hello what is your first name?"
firstName = gets.chomp

puts "Okay cool, now what about your middle names?"
middleName = gets.chomp

puts "Alright, now your last name?"
lastName = gets.chomp

puts "...Okay so your name is " + firstName + " " + middleName + ' ' + lastName

puts "Alright " + firstName + " " + middleName + ' ' + lastName + ". What is your favourite number?"
faveNum = gets.chomp.to_i
faveNum + 1

puts "I think your favourite number is " + faveNum
```

I am getting a TypeError with `no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String (TypeError)`

Could anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? I have looked online and I thought I had the answer when I added .to_i to my faveNum = gets.chomp line. But alas, still nothing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError with no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
>   (TypeError)

The problem is that `favNum` is a number (i.e. `Fixnum`) so, when you try to concatenate it with `+` you get a `TypeError` since you first need to convert it to `String` before using `+`. So, to do that, just change add `to.s` to `faveNum`, like this:

```
puts "I think your favourite number is " + faveNum.to_s
```

Or, in a more idiomatic way, you could use *string interpolation* which calls `to_s` automatically:

```
puts "I think your favourite number is #{faveNum}"
```

> ...the on line 10 (faveNum + 1) this addition is not being carried
>   out.

You are just adding `faveNum` and `1`, but the result is not stored anywhere, so change:

```
faveNum + 1
```

To this:

```
faveNum += 1
```

Using `+=` is the same as doing `faveNum = faveNum + 1`.

Comment: Hi Gerry, Thanks for your quick response. This is sorting the TypeError message however the on line 10 (faveNum + 1) this addition is not being carried out. faveNum has been converted to an integer and I assumed this would solve this. Thank you

Comment: @NickPrice `favNum + 1` is not the same as `favNum = favNum + 1`. Only one of those changes `favNum`.